# Trouble using classes to call an instance on a dataframe object

Tags: python, pandas, class, oop

Newbie at dealing with classes.

I have some dataframe objects I want to transform, but I'm having trouble manipulating them with classes. Below is an example. The goal is to transpose a dataframe and reassign it to its original variable name. In this case, the dataframe is `assets`.

```
import pandas as pd
from requests import get
import numpy as np

html = get("https://www.cbn.gov.ng/rates/Assets.asp").text

table = pd.read_html(html,skiprows=[0,1])[2]
assets = table[1:13]

class Array_Df_Retitle:
    def __init__(self,df):
        self.df = df
        
    def change(self):
        self.df = self.df.transpose()
        self.df.columns = self.df[0]
        return self.df
```

However, calling `assets = Array_Df_Retitle(assets).change()` simply yields an error:

```
KeyError: 0
```

I'd like to know where I'm getting things wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code. The problem is coming from `self.df[0]`. This means you are selecting the column named `0`. However, after transposing, you will not have any column named `0`. You will have a row instead.

```
import pandas as pd
from requests import get
import numpy as np

html = get("https://www.cbn.gov.ng/rates/Assets.asp").text

table = pd.read_html(html,skiprows=[0,1])[2]
assets = table[1:13]

class Array_Df_Retitle:
    def __init__(self,df):
        self.df = df
        
    def change(self):
        self.df = self.df.dropna(how='all').transpose()
        self.df.columns = self.df.loc[0,:]
        return self.df.drop(0).reset_index(drop=True)


Array_Df_Retitle(assets).change()
```

[image]